# SwiftUI view with rounded corners AND border

Tags: swift, swiftui, viewmodifier

```
            ZStack {
                VStack {
                    Text("some text")
                    Button("Ok") {}
                     .foregroundColor(.cyan)
                     .padding()
                }
                .padding()
            }
            .background(.red)
            .border(.blue, width: 5)
            .cornerRadius(20)
```

[image]

I want the entire view to have the blue border with rounded corners (instead of the red square overlapping the rounded blue border. How? I've tried seemingly all variations of ordering the modifiers.

Comment: Why have you added a ZStack?

Comment: Removing the ZStack and placing the modifiers on the VStack results in the same issue.

Answer (score 140, accepted):

SwiftUI borders have straight edges no matter what corner radius you apply ([`.cornerRadius`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/path/cornerradius(_:antialiased:)) simply clips the view to a rounded mask and doesn't adjust the border's appearance).

If you want a rounded border, you'll need to overlay and [`.stroke`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/shape/stroke(_:linewidth:)) a rounded rectangle:

```
VStack {
    Text("some text")
    Button("Ok") {}
        .foregroundColor(.cyan)
        .padding()
}
.padding()
.background(.red)
.cornerRadius(20) /// make the background rounded
.overlay( /// apply a rounded border
    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20)
        .stroke(.blue, lineWidth: 5)
)
```

Result:

[image: Rounded blue border]

Comment: Using strokeBorder() is better. It will not give prevent any problems with edge insets.

Comment: `strokeBorder()` is a crucial modifier! Otherwise it looks like a border made in MS Paint

Answer (score 23):

sometimes just adding the overlay may produce unsatisfying results (this is the case when the used view is designed with infinite width/height)

[for example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AIbgL.png)

so I'd recommend using an inset when trying to add rounded border

```
.overlay(
    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20)
        .inset(by: 5) // inset value should be same as lineWidth in .stroke
        .stroke(.blue, lineWidth: 5)
)
```

Comment: This answer works for HStack etc. too, great! The only thing that worked for me, most other solutions are for buttons but leave strange line width differences, this here does not. Exactly what your sample image shows was my problem, thx!!

Comment: This solution works incredibly well with things like LazyVGrids that have a spacing and you use `.frame(maxWidth: .infinity)` on the elements. Before the spacing was too small then, now with the inset it works like a charm!

Answer (score 6):

Adding over the other answers, here is a neat extension for your `SwiftUI` app:

```
fileprivate struct ModifierCornerRadiusWithBorder: ViewModifier {
    var radius: CGFloat
    var borderLineWidth: CGFloat = 1
    var borderColor: Color = .gray
    var antialiased: Bool = true
    
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content
            .cornerRadius(self.radius, antialiased: self.antialiased)
            .overlay(
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: self.radius)
                    .inset(by: self.borderLineWidth)
                    .strokeBorder(self.borderColor, lineWidth: self.borderLineWidth, antialiased: self.antialiased)
            )
    }
}

extension View {
    func cornerRadiusWithBorder(radius: CGFloat, borderLineWidth: CGFloat = 1, borderColor: Color = .gray, antialiased: Bool = true) -> some View {
        modifier(ModifierCornerRadiusWithBorder(radius: radius, borderLineWidth: borderLineWidth, borderColor: borderColor, antialiased: antialiased))
    }
}
```

You can then just do

```
VStack {
    Text("some text")
    Button("Ok") {}
        .foregroundColor(.cyan)
        .padding()
}
.padding()
.background(.red)
.cornerRadiusWithBorder(radius: 20, borderLineWidth: 5, borderColor: . blue)
```

to achieve this

[image]

Answer (score 5):

```
struct RoundedCorner: Shape {
    var radius: CGFloat = .infinity
    var corners: UIRectCorner = .allCorners
    
    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: rect, byRoundingCorners: corners, cornerRadii: CGSize(width: radius, height: radius))
        return Path(path.cgPath)
    }
}

extension View {
    func roundedCornerWithBorder(lineWidth: CGFloat, borderColor: Color, radius: CGFloat, corners: UIRectCorner) -> some View {
        clipShape(RoundedCorner(radius: radius, corners: corners) )
            .overlay(RoundedCorner(radius: radius, corners: corners)
                .stroke(borderColor, lineWidth: lineWidth))
    }
}
```

How to use different examples.

Example: 1 - Using All Side Corner Radius with Border.

```
  var body: some View {
        Text("Some Text")
            .padding()
            .background(.red)
            .roundedCornerWithBorder(lineWidth: 2, borderColor: .blue, radius: 4, corners: [.allCorners])        
    }
```

[image]

Example: 2 - For Top Left & Bottom Left Side Corner Radius with Border.

```
var body: some View {
    Text("Some Text")
        .padding()
        .background(.red)
        .roundedCornerWithBorder(lineWidth: 2, borderColor: .blue, radius: 20, corners: [.topLeft, .bottomLeft])
}
```

[image]

Example: 3 - For Top Right & Bottom Right Side Corner Radius with Border.

```
var body: some View {
    Text("Some Text")
        .padding()
        .background(.red)
        .roundedCornerWithBorder(lineWidth: 2, borderColor: .blue, radius: 20, corners: [.topRight, .bottomRight])
}
```

[image]

Example: 4 - For Top Left & Bottom Right Side Corner Radius with Border.

```
var body: some View {
    Text("Some Text")
        .padding()
        .background(.red)
        .roundedCornerWithBorder(lineWidth: 2, borderColor: .blue, radius: 20, corners: [.topLeft, .bottomRight])
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Using ".stroke" might be considered a best practice approach. However, if you'd like to try, the following method could also suffice:

```
RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20)
    .foregroundColor(.blue)
    .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
    .overlay(
        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20)
            .foregroundColor(.red)
            .frame(width: 90, height: 90)
            .overlay(
                VStack {
                    Text("some text")
                    Button("Ok") {}
                }
            )
    )
```

You will get the same result with this.