# How to give a view multiple background layer in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui

In SwiftUI, how to achieve below effect, as below example, a text view with lightblue bg color(layer1) and white bg color(layer2).

[image]

I tried with ZStack, but not sure how to provide the same frame for the lightblue color, which is adjust with text view's size.

```
                ZStack {
                    Color(.lightBlue10)
                    Text("BASKETBALL")
                        .font(.custom("AmericanTypewriter", size: 18))
                        .padding(.horizontal, 20)
                        .padding(.vertical, 6)
                        .background(.white)
                        .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 13))
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

Great, I achieve this with `overlay` modifier with this answer's help [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71745004/10158398).

```
                Text("BASKETBALL")
                    .font(.custom("AmericanTypewriter", size: 18))
                    .padding(.horizontal, 20)
                    .padding(.vertical, 6)
                    .background(.lightBlue10)
                    .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20))
                    .overlay(content: {
                        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20)
                            .stroke(.white, lineWidth: 2)
                    })
```

[image]